# Allow a regular use to write in /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, openvpn, proc

I am using a fairly cheap VPN service in my Xubuntu 18.04 (VPN created using OpenVPN) and, as many other VPN services, is leaking my IPv6.

I thought that maybe, since OpenVPN can run a script when it connects or disconnects, I could just temporarily disable IPv6 when the VPN is connected. I don't use it that, *THAT* much, anyway and I always activate it manually through the network manager applet.

I ***think*** (I'm rather unfamiliar with SystemD) that it would be a matter of putting something like this...

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1 
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.tun0.disable_ipv6 = 1
# [... etc, etc, etc ...]
sysctl -p
```

... inside the script to run after OpenVPN is activated.

But all those values are written into the virtual `/proc/` filesystem (right? I think? I might be completely wrong here)

So I would like to know if there's a way of changing the ownership of just `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf` (not the whole `/proc/`) to my regular user (the one that will be connecting to the VPN) so I don't need to manually run the script that disables IPv6 as `sudo` (I would much rather have it run automatically when OpenVPN connects) I imagine I can always have that script running with `root` ownership an `setuid` activated, but that would be a last-resort solution (I am VERY wary of scripts running with `setuid`)

I considered creating a startup SystemD service, but I don't think that's going to be enough, since even as root I can not change ownership of files under `/proc/sys/net...`

```
root@computer:/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf# whoami
root
root@computer:/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf# chown borrajax /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/disable_ipv6
chown: changing ownership of '/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlp3s0/disable_ipv6': Operation not permitted
```

I have also seen people that remount the whole `/proc/` with a different owner, but I don't want to change the whole filesystem's permissions.

Comment: proc is a virtual file system that provides a view in the linux kernel space. You do not want or cant mess up with that. Your best bet is either using sudo restricted to that command or attaching it to the VPN service Unit or some dependency, like scripts ran when DHCP goes up and down. Let's see if someone comes up with a better idea. Btw, in modern linux/Unix you are not able to setuid shell scripts for security reasons.